# SugarCRM support links are broken within modules

Tags: sugarcrm

I recently downloaded and installed sugarcrm community edition: 6.5.17.

How can I fix the help links within the various modules?  Or, how can I figure out how the help calls work, since I can't find any code reference within code to the links being generated.

When I click on a help link within any module, such as within opportunities:

Click here to learn more about the Opportunities module. In order to access more information, use the user menu drop down located on the main navigation bar to access Help.

Where the "click here" link looks like this when viewing the html page source:

href='?module=Administration&action=SupportPortal&view=documentation&version=6.5.17&edition=CE&lang=&help_module=Project&help_action=&key='

I get a "403 Forbidden" error with this link:

[link]http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Application_Guide/13_Opportunities/

I manually found the correct link to be:

[link]http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Sugar_Community_Edition_Application_Guide_6.5.0/13_Opportunities/

[image: Example link that exhibits the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `config_override.php` and add a param for `custom_help_url` that points to a top-level page at the site that you found.

Here's how I found it:

In Sugar, nearly anything you read on the screen is kept in some language file for localization and translation purposes. So we can start by using `grep` to search the system for this bit of translated text:

```
[MKP01] [~/Sites/sugar] > grep -r 'to learn more about the' include/
include//language/en_us.lang.php:   'MSG_EMPTY_LIST_VIEW_NO_RESULTS_SUBMSG' =>  "<item4> to learn more about the <item1> module. In order to access more information, use the user menu drop down located on the main navigation bar to access Help.",
```

Now that we know the name of the label, we can search for instances of when it is used:

```
[MKP01] [~/Sites/nemrace] > grep -r 'MSG_EMPTY_LIST_VIEW_NO_RESULTS_SUBMSG' include/
include//language/en_us.lang.php:   'MSG_EMPTY_LIST_VIEW_NO_RESULTS_SUBMSG' =>  "<item4> to learn more about the <item1> module. In order to access more information, use the user menu drop down located on the main navigation bar to access Help.",
include//ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl:                    {$APP.MSG_EMPTY_LIST_VIEW_NO_RESULTS_SUBMSG|replace:"<item1>":$moduleName|replace:"<item4>":$helpLink}
```

The first result there we already know about, but the second is what you're after: it's the default Smarty template for all list views. If we open that file in a text editor we can trace the definition for variable `$helpLink` is only a few lines above where it's used:

```
{capture assign="helpLink"}<a target="_blank" href='?module=Administration&action=SupportPortal&view=documentation&version={$sugar_info.sugar_version}&edition={$sugar_info.sugar_flavor}&lang=&help_module={$currentModule}&help_action=&key='>{$APP.LBL_CLICK_HERE}</a>{/capture}
```

Then you know to dig into `modules/Administration/SupportPortal.php` and reading that logic, know to look for the definition of function `get_help_url`. We find it in `include/utils.php`

```
function get_help_url($send_edition = '', $send_version = '', $send_lang = '', $send_module = '', $send_action = '', $dev_status = '', $send_key = '', $send_anchor = '') {
    global $sugar_config;

    if (!empty($sugar_config['custom_help_url'])) {
        $sendUrl = $sugar_config['custom_help_url'];
    } else {
        if (!empty($sugar_config['custom_help_base_url'])) {
            $baseUrl= $sugar_config['custom_help_base_url'];
        } else {
            $baseUrl = "http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/product_doc.php";
        }
        $sendUrl = $baseUrl . "?edition={$send_edition}&version={$send_version}&lang={$send_lang}&module={$send_module}&help_action={$send_action}&status={$dev_status}&key={$     send_key}";
        if(!empty($send_anchor)) {
            $sendUrl .= "&anchor=".$send_anchor;
        }
    }
    return $sendUrl;
}
```

This is great news - Sugar understands that some system administrators would wish to provide their own help URls or base URLs, so my recommendation to you would be open `config_override.php` and add a param for `custom_help_url` that points to a top-level page at the site that you found.

Comment: Thanks Matthew your quick fix and your logic to browse code in language def's, smarty, php, and modules was extremely helpful.  I added this line to config_override.php for a satisfactory solution: `$sugar_config['custom_help_url'] = 'http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Sugar_Community_Edition_Application_Guide_6.5.0/';`

Comment: I also posted this question to the SugarCRM community forum. The community manager has marked this issue as a bug: {link}(https://community.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm/topics/application-guide-broken-help-links)